# Probability that randomly picking $4$ out of $90$ numbers yields an ascending sequence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Probability: In a box there are $90$ slips, numbered from $1$ to $90$.  Alex picks up four slips at random, one after the other, without replacement.  Find the probability that the numbers on the slips, in the order he picks up, are in ascending order.

---

**My attempt:**

Sample space = picking up 4 slips one-by-one without replacement should be as good as picking 4 slips at a time which can be done in ${90 \choose 4}$ ways

Now each of these equally likely ${90 \choose 4}$ outcomes will provide us 1 favourable outcome as well in which all four slips would be in ascending order, but then this would be simply $\frac{{90 \choose 4}*1 }{90 \choose 4}$ , however this isn't correct .  Please help me by stating the flaw in my argument and helping me with the correct thought process.

Any approach without the involvement of combinatorics would also be appreciated.

Comment: The combinatorics answer is $\dfrac{\frac{90!}{4! 86!}}{\frac{90!}{86!}} =\dfrac{1}{4!}$  In the denominator, $\frac{90!}{86!}$ is the number of equally likely ways of picking up four slips at random, **one after the other**, without replacement and **recording their order**.  The numerator $\frac{90!}{4! 86!}$ is the number of these which have them **in ascending order**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the original question, with emphasis added by me:

> Find the probability that the numbers on the slips, **in the order he picks up**, are in ascending order.

From your attempt:

> picking up 4 slips one-by-one without replacement should be as good as picking 4 slips at a time

If he picks up all four slips at one time, how can we even talk about "the order he picks up"?

---

That's your error in a nutshell. Note that so far we haven't said anything about combinatorics.

---

If the intuitive answer that was written an hour before this one does not convince you,
you might want to try your attempt again, but with a more appropriate sample space.
In particular, you must not ignore "the order he picks up" in the problem statement.

You counted the sets of four slips Alex could pick, but it makes no sense to ask whether the elements of a sets are in ascending order. Instead, you could count the *sequences* of four slips that Alex could pick.
The number of possible sequences is the number of permutations of $4$ objects out of $90$, sometimes written ${}^4P_{90}$, and it is equal to

$$ \frac{90!}{(90-4)!} = 90 \cdot 89\cdot 88\cdot 87. $$

Now count the number of favorable outcomes. I think you already know how to do this, because you gave the reasoning in your question.

Comment: +1 Nice! Pointing out the specific point where OP's thought process goes wrong is much more helpful than just providing the right answer.

Answer (score 37):

What matters here is the order of the slips, not which slips Alex selects.  Regardless of which four slips Alex selects, there are $4!$ orders in which Alex could select them.  Of these, only one is in ascending order.  Hence, the probability that Alex selects the slips he does select in ascending order is
$$\frac{1}{4!}$$

Comment: ATQ, The slips have to be selected though , right ? I am not able to understand how does it not matter which 4 slips Alex picks up

Comment: @VasuGupta  Pick any 4 numbers at random from the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,90\}.~$  For example, assume that the numbers chosen (in some order) are $~\{15, 37, 83, 67\}.~$  There are $~4!~$ different ways of ordering the numbers in this set, and only one of the $~4!~$ orderings places the numbers in strictly ascending order.

Comment: @VasuGupta Another way to look at it: Alex first picks 4 slips without looking at them, keeps them upside down and then reorders them in random order. What is the probability that they are now in ascending order? This two-step procedure is equivalent to the question, but now it's probably clearer that we can answer the question without knowing what numbers the slips are (as long as we know they're all different so there are no ties to confuse us): the probability that 4 different numbers sorted randomly are in ascending order.

Comment: @JiK: Perhaps add an extra step: he draws the slips, writes "A" on the lowest, "B" on the second lowest, "C" on the second highest, and "D" on the highest.  He then flips them over and has someone shuffled.  What is the probability that they will be in the order ABCD.

Answer (score 13):

@NFTaussig 's answer is the correct one. Here's a more concrete way to think it through. First imagine a simpler problem: just two slips from among a million.

There are very many ways to pick those two slips., but you do not have to count them. Among those many ways, there are just two ways to pick the slips numbered $15$ and $37$. Each of the two possible orders is equally likely. Clearly the same is true for any pair.

How about three slips numbered $8$, $19$ and $256$? There are just $6=3 \times 2$ ways to get those - each of the six possible orders. And they are equally likely. So the chance that they are in increasing order is $1/6$.

Now generalize.

Answer (score 3):

There are four numbers that you pick. There is a largest, a second largest, a third largest, and a smallest.

They are in ascending order if you pick the smallest first, then the third largest, then the second largest, then the largest. The chance for that is (1/4) * (1/3) * (1/2) * 1 = 1/(4!) = 1/24.

How many numbers there are in the pot is completely irrelevant as long as there are at least 4, and all different.

Answer (score 1):

> Please help me by stating the flaw in my argument and helping me with the correct thought process.

The error is that you are counting successful ordered hands in your numerator and comparing that to the number of unordered hands in the denominator; this is a faulty "Apples to Oranges" comparison.

Essentially, one could write it out as the following:
$$
\frac{(\mbox{Number of Possible Hands})\cdot(\mbox{Number of Successful Orderings for That Hand})}{(\mbox{Number of Possible Hands})\cdot(\mbox{Number of Total Orderings for That Hand})}
$$
If we then decide to call these number of orderings as $N_s$ for the succesful number, and $N_f$ for the failing orders, then $N_{total}=N_s+N_f$ and we could work out your example as follows:
$$
\frac{\binom{90}{4}\cdot(N_s)}{\binom{90}{4}\cdot(N_s+N_f)} = \frac{\binom{90}{4}\cdot(1)}{\binom{90}{4}\cdot(1+N_f)}\rightarrow\frac{\binom{90}{4}\cdot(1)}{\binom{90}{4}}
$$
where you are correct about $N_s=1$ having one possible ordering... but in your denominator you have forgotten to also consider the contribution of the unsuccessful orderings for that hand. (Essentially, you have accidentally set $N_f=0$ as if there are no bad orderings!)

The way to fix this is to find the proper $N_f$ value so that your $N_{total}$ becomes correct.